# Mongo:Exception OperationFailure: unrecognized field 'mergeByPBRT'

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have an aggregation query which looks like:

```
pipeline = [
            {"$match": {"col_name": "value"}},
            {"$group": {"_id": "value"}},
            {"$group": {"_id": "null", "count": {"$sum": 1}}}
        ]
result = Itablename.objects.aggregate(*pipeline, allowDiskUse=True)
```

I am getting error `Exception OperationFailure: unrecognized field 'mergeByPBRT'`

I didn't have `mergeByPBRT` field in my aggregation query. I have tried changing the version.

Current version: 4.0.13
Tried version: 3.0.0,3.7

Can you please help me try to solve this?

Comment: Try to remove `{"$group": {"_id": "value"}},` stage

Comment: Your query looks ok, can you try running it directly on mongoDB & check if it's an issue with code(maybe a driver thing or code)

Comment: in my host computer it is working fine but for mongo servers it is not.I have run the code in mongodb i was getting same error

Answer (score 1):

updated versions in replicaset of mongo.It worked.